# React Hooks - Unable to get updated state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am having problem with my uploadStatus state. I am not getting the updated value of react-hooks state. If I added console.log() inside the fileOnProgress(), I am getting [] value of uploadStatus state.

I tried putting the uploadStatus state in useEffect but infinite loop happens because the state is updating also inside the function.

NOTE: In this scenario the uploadStatus is already populated from other function, that's why I am expecting to get the updated value.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function Dropzone {

  const [ uploadStatus, setUploadStatus ] = useState([]);
  const [ resumableFiles, setResumableFiles ] = useState([]);

  const resumableListener = () => {
      if (resumableFiles.length === 0) return;
      resumableFiles.map(resumable => {
          resumable.on('progress', () => {
              fileOnProgress(resumable);
          });
          resumable.on('fileError', (error) => {
              console.log(error)
          });
      });
  };

  const fileOnProgress = (resumable) => {
      const file = resumable.files[0];
      const size = (file.size / 1048576).toFixed(2);
      const progress = (resumable.progress() * 100).toFixed(2).toString() + '%';
      const cont = [...uploadStatus];

      cont.map(d => {
          if (d.id === file.uniqueIdentifier) {
              d.status = progress;
          }
      });
      setUploadStatus(cont);  
  };

  useEffect(() => {
      resumableListener();
  }, [resumableFiles]);

  ...

}
```

Comment: Where are you actually updating `uploadStatus` - is it only inside `fileOnProgress` ? because you are just spreading the current value into a new array... which will just be the old value. `Array.map` returns a new array so unless you assign it and use it nothing will happen.

Comment: Shouldn't your `.map` return something?
`const x = cont.map(d => { if(d.id === file.uniqueId){d.status = progress} return d;  })`

Comment: @ajmajmajma please read the note. I just simplified and put the code block that has a problem. I have another function that adds value in uploadStatus state. And in that scenario, uploadStatus is already populated a value.

Comment: Well you have a problem with your map inside `fileOnProgress` - but if at that point in time it is already suppose to have another value (aside from the initiated empty array) you may have other problems and might need to show that code.

Answer (score 3):

`Array.map` returns a new array, so try :

```
  const newCont = cont.map(d => {
      if (d.id === file.uniqueIdentifier) {
          d.status = progress;
      }

      return d;
  });
  setUploadStatus(newCont);
```

As pointed out by @go_diego , you are also missing the return in the map.

[MDN docs for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: You haven't returned anything though.  Needs a `return d`

Comment: I forget the return all the time too.